# In Chrome DevTools, how to get file size WITHOUT reloading the page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I know that switching to the Network tab in Chrome DevTools and reloading the page will show the size of each request, but in this particular case, I'd just built and pushed a new version of the page, and belatedly realized I hadn't looked at the current page size before doing that.

Is there a way to see the size of an already fetched file without reloading the page, perhaps in the Sources or Application tabs in DevTools?

Answer (score 0):

One slightly kludgy way of doing this is opening the desired file in the Sources tab, then clicking in the code pane and selecting all (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

The footer at the bottom of the pane will then show the total number of characters selected.  Divide by 1024 to get the uncompressed size in KB.  But maybe there's a simpler way of getting this info?